# Gradle can't user JAVA_HOME while debugging from Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to compile a project in android studio and it gives the

> Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.

I've already red that to gather more information i should use:

```
gradlew compileDebug --stacktrace
```

from the main folder, but when i do that i get that error:

> JAVA_HOME is set toan invalid directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Jre7\bin\java.exe;

Please note that i tried to use a 64 bit version of the jre too in the JAVA_HOME path.

Anyone can give me some help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value of environment variable **`JAVA_HOME`** to **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Jre7\`** instead of **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Jre7\bin\java.exe`**

**`JAVA_HOME`** should be always pointing to the parent directory of JDK or JRE installation inside of which, we find the **`bin`** directory containing the java, javac, etc. binaries

Answer (score 2):

I might be reading too much into the error message, but shouldn't JAVA_HOME look more like `C:\views\p4\library\bea-jrockit\1.6.0_29\windows-x86_64\dist`?

Notice that it points to a folder called 'dist' instead of to the java.exe itself. To help you figure out the folder, 'dist' has inside of it 'bin'. So maybe try something more like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Jre7\`?