# How to get the JDK path in Gradle within Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle

In order to build some Android projects, it's necessary to set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`. (See [this Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047549/gradle-cant-user-java-home-while-debugging-from-android-studio) and [flutter bug report](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8515).)

This is the case for a project I'm working on. I would like to change the Gradle file so it is not necessary to set `JAVA_HOME`.

**Is there any way for Gradle to get the path to the JDK used by the enclosing Android Studio process (or for the process to pass in the JDK without user intervention)?** This should work when `JAVA_HOME` had not been set.

Comment: Just re-tagged the question with more general tags, because Gradle does not need Android Studio, at all.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Even though this question is about the interaction of Android Studio with Gradle?

Comment: Gradle does not get that path from Android Studio, but either from it's own configuration or from an environmental variable (both ways shown below).When building with Android Studio,Gradle is just called on the CLI but else has not much too do with it; it's a daemon which spawns workers.

Answer (score 5):

There are generally two options available:

a) Edit the `gradle.properties` file and define which JDK you want to use:

```
org.gradle.java.home=(path to JDK home)
```

There it cannot be set dynamically, because it's an egg/hen problem.

And it might also fail on other computers, because the path may vary.

But one can pass it as command-line option:

```
./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.java.home=$JAVA_PATH
```

For reference: [Build Environment](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

---

b) However, one can also add an `export JDK_HOME` statement on top of file `gradlew`. Came up with a shell script, which can at least detect the default JDK install on Linux (Android Studio runs on JRE):

```
tmp=`which java`
export JAVA_HOME=${tmp::-9}


echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_172
```

Of course, one also would have to consider no JDK being present at all:

```
/usr/bin/which: no java in ...
```

Generally, this assumes a default JDK had been set with [alternatives](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Communications_Platform/5.1/html/Platform_Installation_Guide/sect-Setting_the_Default_JDK.html), as a package manger usually would do; eg `yum install jdk1.8.0_102.x86_64`. The problem here is, that there is no easy way to identify which JDK path to use on Windows, because Windows has no `which` command and one would likely have to read from the registry. A helper PS script or executable could look up the value and truncate as required, called from file `gradlew.bat`. There still may be other ways to get the path.

Comment: 'which java' didn't work because Android Studio did not update the path or set an environment variable when installing the JDK. In any case, our goal is to make this work automatically without requiring the user to do anything. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: @EllenSpertus this sets the variable dynamically on Linux, when adding it into file `gradlew` on top... assuming java is even installed. As stated above, `gradlew` is being called through the CLI, therefore Windows and Linux differ.

Comment: I'm afraid that advice to use
tmp=`which java`
export JAVA_HOME=${tmp::-9}
does nor work in Ubuntu20.04, because JAVA-HOME will be just  '/usr' and should point '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/' if we use standard java. This is because Ubuntu uses symlinks and alternatives settings, which are complicated to parse, what is the final target.

Answer (score 4):

you can define a task in `your_project_path/app/build.gradle`

```java
task javaHome {
    println "JAVA_HOME:" + System.getProperty("java.home")
}
```

run task:

```sh
./gradlew -q app:javaHome
```

RESULT:

```
JAVA_HOME:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer my question, which was how to get the path to the JDK used by Android Studio if the user *has not* set the environment variable. I have modified my question to make it clearer.