# Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161 contains a valid JDK installation

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm following along with the Udacity lesson on creating our first jar file. It says to apply the plugin and simply run 'gradle jar'.

```
    /*

Solution:

*/

apply plugin: 'java' // 1. Apply the Java plugin to the project

//2. Simply run `gradle jar`
```

however I'm getting an error:

```
$ gradle jar
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161 contains a valid JDK installation.
```

I have created an environmental variable JAVA_HOME and added the value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1 suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815/unable-to-locate-tools-jar).

I've also gone into the project structure, JDK location, and changed that to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1.

Neither has worked... how do I proceed with this lesson and creating a jar file?

Comment: Think there is an issue of mismatch as Gradle error message says-Java\jre1.8.0_161 contains a valid JDK installation and you are adding jdk-12.0.1 in Java_Home. Strongly recommend to visit these SO Questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988601/do-i-need-both-jdk-and-jre              
                                     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601827/should-java-home-point-to-jdk-or-jre

Comment: Yeah I think somehow android studio is reading from the x86 program file and not the regular program files, but I don't know how to change this.

Comment: These links can help you in this. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/how-do-i-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version       https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896683/how-to-get-the-jdk-path-in-gradle-within-android-studio